# lubridate parse_date_time() sometimes off by 1 usec

Tags: r, lubridate

parse_date_time() is giving me some results that differ in their usec location by 1 unit, for example:

```
options(digits.secs=10)
 
> parse_date_time("2022-06-14 10:08:00.000242", "Y-m-d H:M:OS", tz="" )
[1] "2022-06-14 10:08:00.000241 CEST"
> parse_date_time("2022-06-14 10:08:00.000435", "Y-m-d H:M:OS", tz="" )
[1] "2022-06-14 10:08:00.000434 CEST"
> parse_date_time("2022-06-14 10:08:00.021961", "Y-m-d H:M:OS", tz="" )
[1] "2022-06-14 10:08:00.02196 CEST"
```

I'm guessing this is round off error somewhere?  Is there anyway to tell parse_date_time() to use greater precision when calculating the fractional seconds value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `strptime` might be superior.

```
options(digits.secs=6)

strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="")
# [1] "2022-06-14 10:08:00.000242 CEST" "2022-06-14 10:08:00.000435 CEST"
# [3] "2022-06-14 10:08:00.021961 CEST"
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("2022-06-14 10:08:00.000242", "2022-06-14 10:08:00.000435", "2022-06-14 10:08:00.021961")
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks,  Any idea why the difference?