# as.POSIXct sometimes off by 1 usec

Tags: r, posixct

This is, perhaps, somewhat related to my previous question, [lubridate parse_date_time() sometimes off by 1 usec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72740884/lubridate-parse-date-time-sometimes-off-by-1-usec), as it has the same kind of symptoms, but I need to end up with a POSIXct for ggplot.

strptime() correctly converts a time, but as.POSIXct sometime mangles the final uS:

```
> options(digits.secs=10)

> as.POSIXct(strptime("2022-08-10 11:25:00.000155", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz=""))
[1] "2022-08-10 11:25:00.000154 CEST"

> strptime("2022-08-10 11:25:00.000155", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz="")
[1] "2022-08-10 11:25:00.000155 CEST"
```

Comment: POSIXct values are stored as a single floating point number. There's just not enough resolution in a floating point number to accurately tract microseconds like that. `strptime` returns a `POSIXlt` which has separate fields for hours/minutes/seconds so it's able to retain a higher precision. What is the actual plotting problem you are having? Do you need to be able to tell the difference between .000154 and .000155 on a plot? That seems like it would be hard to do visually.

Comment: Ah, that would appear to be the answer, single-precision fp, thanks.  For the purposes of plotting, there's no problem, it just means my df needs to carry around the original as well in case I need the full resolution later on (this variable is going to change to ns resolution at some stage).  I'll fork off a low resolution version for plotting.  Many thanks.